# Has or Have use?

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct?

1. He haven't got the keys yet.
2. He hasn't got the keys yet.

Answer (score 1):

2 is right. When you use “he/she/it” you want to use “has” in the present tense or when we use it as a helping verb.

In English, the third person singular (he/she/it) usually takes a verb that ends in -s.

E.g.  He lives with his sister. VS We live with our sister.

“Have” is an irregular verb, and we use “has” when we need the -s ending.

Answer (score 0):

> Which one is correct?
>
> He haven't got the keys yet.
>
> He hasn't got the keys yet.

The answer is "He **has**n't got the keys yet".

The present tense of the verb "to have":

I have

You have

He/she/it **has**

We have

You have

They have